# Java типы, допускающие NULL значения

Tags: java, c#, null

Существуют ли в Java что-то вроде типов, допускающих `NULL` значения? То есть с сервера приходит, на пример, `int`, но вместо него может прийти `NULL` В C#можно это обработать, используя типы, допускающие, `NULL` значения.

```
int? a = NULL;
```

Как это следует обрабатывать в Java?

Comment: Использовать классы-обёртки примитивов: вместо `int` -> `Integer` и т.п.

Comment: @AndreyM оформите как ответ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В Java ссылка любого класса может принимать значение `null`.
Примитивы же...

1. Целые числа - `byte`, `short`, `char`, `int`, `long`
2. Числа с плавающей точкой (иначе дробные) - `float`, `double`
3. Логический - `boolean`

...лишены такой возможности.

> Если требуется создать ссылку на один из примитивных типов данных, необходимо использовать соответствующий класс-обертку. Также в таких классах есть некоторые полезные методы и константы, например минимальное значение типа int можно узнать использовав константу Integer.MIN_VALUE. Оборачивание примитива в объект называется упаковкой (boxing), а обратный процесс распаковкой (unboxing). [(источник)](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%8B_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85)

Соответственно для решения вашей задачи необходимо использовать классы-обёртки примитивов: `int` -> `Integer`, `short` -> `Short` и т.п.

Answer (score 0):

В java для этого используются классы обертки:

> wrapper for int: Integer
>
> wrapper for double: Double

Но будьте внимательно, типы вроде `Integer` передаются по ссылке, а не по значению.

Comment: Что такое "Integer wrapper for double"?

Comment: Запятую забыл.
wrapper for int: Integer; wrapper for double: Double